# Is there a benefits of using closures in this case

Tags: javascript

Here in this code is used closure:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var output = document.getElementById('Output');
    var closure = myClosure();
    output.innerHTML = closure();

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        output.innerHTML += '<br />' + closure();
    }, 500);
}

function myNonClosure() {
    var date = new Date();
    return date.getMilliseconds();
}

function myClosure() {
    var date = new Date();

    return function() {
        return date.getMilliseconds();
    }
}
```

I am just wondering what are benefits of using closure version of function against non-closure function ?

```
output.innerHTML = myNonClosure();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `myClosure` will always return the same value as `var date = new Date();` will be executed only once. But function `myNonClosure` will return **current amount of milliseconds**. So they are not identical.